# Html.ActionLink not forming link in the format that I want

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quick newbie question. I don't know why my Html.ActionLink that translates to this in 'View Source'

```
<a href="/Customer/CustomerSave?custid=1104">Save</a>
```

My Html helper looks like this:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Save", "CustomerSave","Customer",new {custid = 101 })%>
```

I'm getting a 'Resource not found' error when trying to reach my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomerSave(int custid)
{
........
}
```

Clearly the anchor is not well formed.  I've read other posts and tried other options but I don't fully understand what's going on.  All I'm trying to do is hit the action ("CustomerSave") in my Customer Controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't you posting to server information to save your customer? Where data comes from?

Answer (score 3):

Change your `CustomerSave` to HTTPGet or remove HTTPPost.

```
[HttpPost] //<-- Here
public ActionResult CustomerSave(int custid)
{
........
}
```

You are getting the error because ActionLink is Going as HttpGet while your action has HTTPPost attribute marked on it. If you want to make it a post you can try making an Ajax POST request to your action on click of the link. Default Action URl link click will perform a `GET` request.

Try this way

```
       @Ajax.ActionLink("Save", 
             "CustomerSave",
            "Customer",
             new {custid = 101 },
            new AjaxOptions {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnSuccess = "saveCustomer"
        }) ;
```

and JS

```
 function saveCustomer(response, status, data) {

       // Here you get any response
    }
```

or you can go with plain [Jquery Ajax POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) in the click handler for customerSave link.

Comment: I want to post data to my action to insert new customer data.  I have an example of a link that looks like this: <%: Html.ActionLink("Add", "CarCreate", "Car", new { id = Model.custId }, new object { }) %> which produces <a href="/Car/CarCreate/100?returnPage=CustEdit&amp;returnId=690">Add</a>.  This posts data to the controller action using HttpPost which works.

Comment: You can use Ajax Post in that case

Comment: Where is your data to be posted? Is this inside a Form?

Comment: No, I'm not going down the ajax/javascript route for two reasons.  Testing is difficult and I'm not familiar enough with it.  I did say in my opening post that I'm new to this so to suggest I learn Ajax and javascript just to do what should be simple is like suggesting a marathon runner uses a speed boat instead of running shoes.

Answer (score 0):

In your Global.asax.cs file RegisterRoutes method should be like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "CustomerSave", custid = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
       }
```

and your controller method should have same parameter custid.

Answer (score 0):

Html.ActionLink creates an anchor tag and these are GET only.

Try using an Ajax.ActionLink:

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("Save", "CustomerSave","Customer",new {custid = 101 }, new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod="Post"})%>
```